# Prestashop integration API - advice

Tags: php, prestashop

I have online store based on Prestashop. I'd like to sell products based on stock images (API at fotolia.com). I'm going to create module for Prestashop to display categorized photos from fotolia.com and allow user to select a part of the photo. I also want to allow customers to buy standard products.

Example: http://fotoliafull.egzyl.pl/fototapeta-23-Biuro.html

My questions:

1. Do I have to create several modules and template files to handle: categories, product pages, search results?
2. Can I make my module the way it will fit every theme?
3. How can I add product to the cart? Products will be displayed using API response. I guess I have to use some existing Cart controller?

My idea is to create :

- module to handle basic settings (API Key, SEO, etc.)
- module to display list of categories
- module to display contents of categories
- module to display product page
- module to display searchbox
- module to display search results

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't have to
2. No, you can't
3. You can add product to the cart Cart controller

Try to do it with less modules as possible.

No need for module for "list of categories". PS already have controller/templates for that. You just need to override them.

No need for module for "contents of categories". PS already have controller/templates for that. You just need to override them.

No need for module for "product page". PS already have controller/templates for that. You just need to override them.

If you need search box with different functionality that you can't do with ovierriding the core Controller/Templates, you can do it with a separate module that covers the "search results as well.

If it's required to do a separate module, searchbox and search results should be part of it, not in a separate modules.

Comment: Thanks. I will override controller which make listing of products. Will it affect stadard product listing? For example, I want to sell stickers (based on stock images) and clothes (as completely different product).

Comment: If the templates are very different, you can add different templates for both and set the "if" clause at the overriden controller. If the differences are small, you can do them with {if}s at the template.